# How can I solve this limit of an integral?

Tags: integration

I think this can be done with a substitution, the problem is I just don't find it, I've tried maybe:
$$v=e^{4r}$$
$$r=\frac{\ln v}{4}$$

then take the derivative but don't know what to do next

\begin{align*}
\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{1}{r}\int_{1}^{\exp(4r)}\sqrt{1 + \frac{3}{x}}\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}

The solution says the answer is $8$

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Include this in your question, otherwise it's going to get closed.

Answer (score 2):

Let the antiderivative of the integrand be $F(x)$. You are asked to evaluate

$$\lim_{r\to0}\frac{F(e^{4r})-F(1)}{r}.$$

By L'Hospital, this is

$$\lim_{r\to0}4e^{4r}\,f(e^{4r})=4f(1).$$